# Primitive to a function. Is there one?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a primitive function to:

$$\int \! \frac{\int \! \frac{\ln(x+1)\, \mathrm{d} x}{x}\, \mathrm{d} x}{x}$$

Comment: Yes, any continuous function has a primitive (=antiderivative) by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) a primitive function?

This looks something like $-\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)+k_2+k_1 \ln x$.

Comment: I get a feeling that the OP used the term "primitive" function in the sense of an antiderivative, rather than an "elementary" function.

Comment: The OP's integral is almost the defining integral for the trilogarithm.